# eclipse listening on port 8000

Tags: django, eclipse

My eclipse somehow starts listening on port 8000. I have no idea why it does so. I am using Eclipse for Python development (using PyDev tools).

This default port conflicts with default Django development server port viz 8000. I am not able to start Django development version. Off course I can shutdown eclipse, start Django and then restart eclipse, but I would prefer to disable the usage of port 8000 by Eclipse.

On Internet I saw some references to remote debugging capabilities of Eclipse, but could not figure out how to change this default port number.

Comment: Do you have the PDT add on for Eclipse?  I know that was interfering with another development server that I was running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that this problem was happening because of Aptana JavaScript Debug Console which attempts to start a builtin HTTP server in port range (8000 onwards whichever port it finds available first). I just changed this port range in preferences and now I am good.

Comment: By the way, I found these settings under Preferences > Aptana > HTTP Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start Django's development server on a another port, just add this parameter:

```
python manage.py runserver 8001
```

Comment: yes I can do that, but I created a number of bookmarks with the 8000 port in them. So I will have to change them all.